# parsererror status 'ok'. error code 200

Tags: jqgrid

When i submit my JqGrid edit form, i am getting **'parsererror status 'ok'. error code 200'** . can some one help me in getting to know why this error occurs, though i am getting response from server. 
below are my codes
 `beforeShowForm: function(form){
    $('#tr_ArticleID',form).hide();
    $('#tr_ContractNo',form).hide();
 },
 url: "/JqGridDemo/prfArticle.do"`
   Also how should i get the response status (success / failed ) from server in a message box.
And how this submit button in jqGrid works??
i am using json here. many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution Wahab, You are parsing the [HTTP Status Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Doubtlessly, parsing OK will lead to an error. I don't know jqgrid but you need to fetch the response. Not the header information.

Comment: yes u r right. thanks for the information. now i am getting some light on it. i didn't fetch the response correctly.